# Delayed drop down menus without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Do you know any dropdown menu scripts out there written in plain javascript, but not relying on jQuery?

I know how to achieve this with CSS, but I'd also like to add a nice fade effect and make it wait 1 second after the mouse is outside the menu, then close it if the mouse doesn't come back within the menu area.

I think I could implement the fade effect using the CSS "transition" property, but I have no clue on how to add the delay on mouseOut

Comment: maybe try using any of these http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm

Comment: Hint: "mouseout" is when ":hover" stops being true ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this one, it's only 1.2 KB, the code is simple to modify:

http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/11/drop-down-menu/

You can change the time by modifying the "t" variable.

Comment: tx, I found this one on the same site: http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/04/javascript-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `transition-delay`-property and do the following:

- remove the "delay-class", when the user enters the menu
- add the "delay-class" when the user leaves the menu

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition-delay

Or you could do it like this (note: just pseudo code):

```
var timer       = null;

function onenter() {
    showSubMenu();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
}

function onleave() {
    overMenu = false;
    timer    = setTimeout( function () { hideSubMenu(); } , 1000 );
}
```